# Why does ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH no longer work with version adorned binaries

Tags: ubuntu, clang, ubuntu-16.04, address-sanitizer

On Ubuntu 14.10, the `llvm-symbolizer` program is installed as `/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.5`. Normally, address sanitizer wants to find a binary named `llvm-symbolizer` in `PATH`. However, as a workaround, it was possible to explicitly set `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH`. So, setting `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.5` in the environment would let an address sanitizer instrumented program print symbolized errors.

On Ubuntu 16.04, the `llvm-symbolizer` program is again installed with a version suffix, now as `/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.8`. However, the `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` setting no longer seems to work. Running an ASAN instrumented program with `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.8` set in the environment generates the following error when ASAN detects an error:

```
==18718==ERROR: External symbolizer path is set to '/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.8' which isn't a known symbolizer. Please set the path to the llvm-symbolizer binary or other known tool.
```

Does anyone know why this behavior changed, or how to restore the old behavior? This seems unreasonably restrictive. The symbolizer program I've pointed ASAN to is definitely a known symbolizer, it just happens to have an Ubuntu mandated version tag at the end.

Note that adjusting `PATH` doesn't help here, since Ubuntu doesn't ship an `llvm-symbolizer` binary that comes without a version adornment.

Comment: For anyone else who encounters this, it appears that this was the result of [this change in compiler_rt][1]. I've pinged the review to try to determine if this change in behavior was intended, or if this is a regression


  [1]: http://reviews.llvm.org/D8285

Comment: Simplest way to fix this: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.8 /usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer`

Comment: @Eraden Sure, that works fine on my dev box, but this is for a CI system where I can't alter /usr/bin.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It turns out, that on Ubuntu's packaging of LLVM, one can get the unadorned `llvm-symbolizer` binary from the path `/usr/lib/llvm-3.x/bin`, so `PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-3.x/bin:$PATH [COMMAND]` does the trick. I still think though that this change is a regression in compiler_rt.

Answer (score 9):

The following

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.8 /usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer
```

also works for `llvm-symbolizer-4.0`

(copied from @Eraden comment)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I accidentally had written a needless newline character to the `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` env var. So I fixed it with strip() function before writing it to environment variable.